# ArangoDB failed to initialize the database password

Tags: arangodb

Win7 64+ArangoDB 3.4.2 server NSIS

The installation failed and the error is "failed initialize the database passord"
I have tried with the methods this web mentioned https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/arangodb/DCN6vECW1tI

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is not well suited for bugreports, so most probably this page will be deleted anytime soon. 
Please use https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues herefore. 
I just tried with an english version of Windows 7 installed via `Win7_Pro_SP1_English_x64.iso`. 
I tried to install ArangoDB with an empty password and password `a` and both worked out without errors. 
Please describe what exactly you did (like installation directory, password, etc.) and better open a github issue.

Please note that meanwhile ArangoDB 3.4.3 is available, which I used for my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I use windows 10 PRO x64 in Polish language version.
I set the installation directory as (c:\ArangoDB\v3.6.1-comunity) but i try too with default setings,
and I gave the password "pass20"

[image]

https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/11041

**Windows Event Log for aborted instalation of  ArangoDB3-3.6.1_win64.exe**

```
failed to locate javascript.startup-directory directory, its neither available in 'C:\PROGRA~1\PTC\UTILIT~1\MKSTOO~1\usr\share\arangodb3\js' nor in 'C:\ArangoDB\v3.6.1-comunity\C:\PROGRA~1\PTC\UTILIT~1\MKSTOO~1\usr\share\arangodb3\js'
C:\vm04-windows\oskar\work\ArangoDB\lib\Basics\ArangoGlobalContext.cpp
arangodb::ArangoGlobalContext::normalizePath
376
```